# Can a parsed inputTask be used to invoke a runTask in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use sbt as a general task runner (similar to rake/npm). I can get it to parse input the way I want through an inputTask, but I'm absolutely stumped how to use this to invoke a `runTask`/`fullRunTask`

```
val partners: List[Parser[String]] = List("foo", "bar")
val partnerParser = partners.reduce(_ | _)
val acceptArgs = (' ' ~> partnerParser ~ (' ' ~> StringBasic))

lazy val importDump = inputKey[Unit]("Import static data dump")
lazy val importDumpTask = importDump := {
  val (arg1, arg2) = acceptArgs.parsed
  // how can I make this call?
  // ... runTask(Compile, "foo.bar.baz.DoIt.dispatch", arg1, arg2).value
  }
```

I understand that you can't directly call tasks from other tasks, only "depend" on them so the above code won't work.

I know I can do something like

```
mainClass := Some("foo.bar.baz.DoIt.dispatch")
(runMain in Compile).toTask(s" foo.bar.baz.DoIt.dispatch $arg1 $arg2").value
```

But that means I can't use any of the parsing/autocomplete functionality.

So my question is:

**How can I parse input with an `inputTask`, then call a main method in my code with the resulting arguments?**

Comment: alternatively, is sbt just the wrong tool for this job? what's the right way to do this? I am _this_ close to just writing bash script wrappers but I like the idea of sbt setting my classpaths

Comment: Actually, it appears that I can't insert arguments into the `toTask` method because of `Illegal dynamic reference`, so maybe this is totally impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely painful to do in sbt. I would recommend writing a shell script (or using sbt's [built-in `Process` support](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html)).

That said, it's possible to do this by writing a new [`Command`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html) that mutates [the `State` object provided](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.11/api/index.html#sbt.State), adding the tasks you want to run as items in the `remainingCommands` field.

Comment: Thanks, commands looked like the only way to do it to me too. Gonna write some bash runners, I guess